# Why JFrame gets stuck until the operation is finished?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, invokelater, swingutilities

I've created a `JFrame` with a `JButton` "abort".

This `JFrame` shows the status of an operation.

Let's say that function `operation()` contains the code of the operation we want to run.

While the code of function `operation()` is running I can't click the `JButton` "abort" because the `JFrame` is stuck.

So, I thought, that the cause could be the event dispatcher and for this reason I tried to fix the issue using `invokeLater` of `SwingUtilities`:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                operation();
            }
        });
```

But the `JFrame` is still stuck while the code of the operation is running. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: put your `operation()` code into a `new Thread`. Only specific stuff which needs to be invoked Later in there

Comment: Do not perform work in the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html); or your UI will be "stucked".